# drag and drop rows with table-expandable-rows marerial table

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

have a problem with Angular Material table-expandable-rows with drag and drop rows.
the drag and drop doesn't working at all

here the drop function:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  @ViewChild('table') table: MatTable<PeriodicElement>;
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
  expandedElement: PeriodicElement | null;
  
  dropTable(event: CdkDragDrop<PeriodicElement[]>) {
    const prevIndex = this.dataSource.findIndex((d) => d === event.item.data);
    moveItemInArray(this.dataSource, prevIndex, event.currentIndex);
    this.table.renderRows();
  }
}
```

here the example code
[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fjnfwn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: edit: the drag&drop fuctionlity works 
But the extended information for each row does not work well - its always displayed

Answer (score 0):

Now I am with the same problem as you, but I think I have found the solution. Basically the problem was in the row where you reference the cdkDrag.
In addition to the CSS, I have pasted one that is quite ugly but it is working. When i'm ready i leave it nice

https://angular-bgjaeg.stackblitz.io

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bgjaeg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Please do no share just links, it's better to copy the relevant code out of a link as links are not always going to stick around forever.